# Unable to load interest rate from bank website using VBA Excel Web Scraping tools

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

i am new to web scraping and am trying to extract the 36 month bank deposit rate from cambodia (https://www.ababank.com/fixed-deposit/?no_cache=1), but i have encountered an error. I hope i could get some assistance on this as i am new to coding. Thank you very much.

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mPwj.png)

```
Public Sub GetRates()
    Dim appIE As Object
    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    
    With appIE
    .Navigate "https://www.ababank.com/fixed-deposit/?no_cache=1"
    .Visible = False
    End With
    
    Do While appIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Set HTMLTable = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("contenttable mb-15")(0)
    Set TBody = HTMLTable.Children(0) 'The <tbody> tag is the first child
    Set Row = TBody.Children(7) 'The eight <tr> inside the <tbody> tag
    Set Data = Row.Children(1) 'the 2nd column from the row
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = Data
    
End Sub
```

[The data is from a class called contenttable mb-15, 2nd td of the 8th tr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6UUb.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code.  You can copy/paste it directly into your question. `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, not a single element, so you need to reference `getElementsByClassName('blahblah")(0)` (eg to get the first matching element)

Comment: Hi Tim Williams, i have added (0) to the end of my class name, but i encountered run time error 91, Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: The element exists so it is a timing issue. You are attempting to set before the page has loaded that element. Add a condition based timed loop until present or an explicit hard coded wait (less desirable)